# Hiding expand/collapse +/- buttons

Tags: tree, icefaces

Is it possible to hide the +/- buttons for an ICEFaces tree node that is a leaf?  They still appear on my leaf nodes even when I mark that node specifically as a leaf and say node.setAllowsChildren(false).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create an IceUserObject and use it as user object.

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode();
IceUserObject userObject = new IceUserObject(node);
userObject.setLeaf(true);
node.setUserObject(userObject);
```